# Check whether a URL contains www or https:// for RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a scenario where i want to check whether a string contains a url and make it to clickable. I have used regex to convert it into a url. But it only works for http. I want to make it for wwww as well. In the regex which i have i can either add htttp or remove http to include www in a url. 
I have pasted the code in JSfiddle

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm0dbu3t/4/)

```
var convertTextToHTML = $("#systemNotificationMsg").text();
var conversation = convertTextToHTML.replace(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/, function(text, link) {
   return '<a href="http://'+ link +'"> ' + link + ' </a>';
});
```

Comment: I can see its working for `www`. What do you want exactly?

Comment: It is only working if you add http:// at the begining

Comment: In your fiddle, change url to `www.google.com` and add `console.log(link);` before  ` return '<a href="http://'+ link +'"> ' + link + ' </a>';` you can see its returning link for `www`

Comment: If you check, its only returning the one with http and not www

Comment: I posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this, you have to make global match, your regex is finding the first match returning. You have to match multiple `/gi` in regex.

```js
 var convertTextToHTML = $("#systemNotificationMsg").text();
var conversation = convertTextToHTML.replace(/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/gi, function(text, link) {
 console.log("Link in text: "+ link);
   return '<a href="http://'+ link +'"> ' + link + ' </a>';
});
$("#systemNotificationMsg").html(conversation);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="systemNotificationMsg">
This message contains a link to www.google.com/hungerbox
and another to www.google.com so this is the example
</div>
```

Comment: Pls see the 2nd link. It is not getting converted to a clickable link

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can check now both links getting converted to `hyperlinks`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with slightly simpler regex.

I have updated the JSFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxnfq95b/1/

The regex is now:

```
/(www|https?)([^\s]+)/g
```

Please note that the `/g` is required to make it replace all.

`(www|https?)` will match either www. or http(s) links.

`([^\s]+)` will make the regex continue until it hits a space character.

Comment: @tkamath99 please check the updated answer - I had misunderstood you.

Comment: Dawson... I am getting a problem when there is already http:// present in the text. It appends another http:// resulting in an error in URL. Any condition check to remove http:// if already present ?